# EFCore Add Entity with childEntity Throw has tracked same key

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

i`m trying to update my code from ef6 to efcore , in EF 6, give child wrong foregin key value, Context.Set.Add() not Check key . and after Add() , will triggered relationship fix-up(auto modify FK property), then SaveChange , but EF Core when Add() will throw key has already tracked

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.4
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 2.2

```
var defaultPk = "OneCrud_UnitTest";
            var defaultPk2 = "OneCrud_UnitTest2";
            var item1 = new item { ItemGID = defaultPk,ItemID = defaultPk,TS=DateTime.Now };
            item1.itemDetail = new List<itemDetail>();
            var detail1 = new itemDetail() //itemDetail HasKey(t => new { t.ItemGID,t.LineId});
            {
                GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                ItemGID = defaultPk,//this is foregin key 
                LineId = 1
            };
            item1.itemDetail.Add(detail1);
            unitOfWork.DataContext.Set<item>().Add((item1));
            unitOfWork.Commit();

            var item = itemRepository.GetByID(defaultPk);
            var item2 = new item { ItemGID = defaultPk2 };
            item2.ItemID = item2.ItemGID;
            item2.TS = DateTime.Now;
            item2.itemDetail = new List<itemDetail>();
            item2.itemDetail.Add(new itemDetail {
                ItemGID = defaultPk, //in ef 6 will auto fix up to defaultPk2 after Add(), and not throw exception 
                LineId = 1,
                GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            });
            unitOfWork.DataContext.Set<item>().Add((item2)); // in ef core this line will throw exception "has tracked same key  ItemGID[OneCrud_UnitTest],LineId[1]"
            unitOfWork.Commit();
```

may i disable the save key check, or fix up foreign key value by hand before call Add() method

Comment: this problem is moved to here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/16171